# How to install a newer version of a package using apt on Raspberry Pi OS?

Tags: apt

I would like to avoid compiling [zbar](https://github.com/mchehab/zbar) from source.

Latest version available on Raspberry Pi OS (found using `apt-cache madison zbar-tools`) is `0.22` while latest release on GitHub is `0.23.90`.

Comment: wait for "someone at debian" to compile a later version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [How to install never version of package using apt on Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/124048/how-to-install-never-version-of-package-using-apt-on-raspberry-pi-os)

You can't.

The repository contains the packages that are available in the distro.  If you want something that is not there, you will have to get it from somewhere else.

Ideally, it can be built easily enough from source.

It's also not impossible to manually dissect a package from a different distro, eg., Ubuntu or Fedora, if you can find it for the correct platform ("armhf" for 32 bit RpiOS, arm64 for the 64-bit version).  However, in most cases the issue you will run into is that the executable links to a newer version of the system C library.  At that point you are deep in the weeds and should seriously consider other options.

*How* to manually dissect linux distro packages is off-topic here and should be taken up at [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks! Would you happen to know what might be causing a seg fault when I run latest version of zbarcam compiled from source (please see [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/124052/how-to-compile-zbar-on-raspberry-pi-os) question)?

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132193/25985 Unfortunately you are probably up a creek unless you understand and can debug the source.